# how many graphs with vertices $\{a,b,c,d\}$ exist such that each vertex lies in exactly one cycle of length at most $2$?

Tags: graph-theory

In a attempt to answer [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760631/finding-number-of-functions-from-a-set-to-itself-such-that-ffx-x) question I came up with the following answer:

This can be asked as a graph theory problem: how many directed graphs with outdegree $1$ and vertices $\{a,b,c,d\}$ exist such that each vertex lies in exactly one cycle of length at most $2$?

Case 1: All cycles are of length 1. This is equivalent to the identity function, which we know is unique. However from a graph theoretic point of view this is equal to $\binom{4}{4}$ because we are choosing 4 vertices to have cycle length one (notice that order does not matter because cycles start and end in the same place, and if two functions have the same cycles regardless of order they are equal). $\binom{4}{4} = 1$, consistent with what we know about the identity.

Case 2: One cycle is of length 2, and 2 are of length one. We know that the two of length one are chosen by $\binom{4}{2}$ and the reaming two vertices are forces to be in the cycles of length two (or are 'chosen' by $\binom{2}{2}$).

Case 3: 2 cycles of length 2, which is the same ammount of choices as above, since the two remaining ones are forced to be the cycle.

Summing the amounts of functions from the three cases we get $13$.

However, it disagrees with the other answers and I'm not sure what I did wrong. Is my question not equivalent? Did I count incorrectly?

Comment: You forgot to account for the possibility of edges that are not part of cycles. (And you're overcounting your case 3; choosing {a,b} or {c,d} as the first 2-cycle gives rise to the same graph).

Comment: Hmm ... looking at the earlier question it looks like you may have intended to say not just "graphs" (by which I understood undirected multigraphs, since you have cycles of length 1 and 2), but "directed graphs where every vertex have outdegree $1$". That should have been in your question!

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant to say, but I didn't know that outdegree was a term. I will fix that. My problem is then simply over-counting on part three, which I am not sure how to fix. Do I just divide by 2?

Comment: x @Juan: Yes, that's the usual way to deal with overcounting when you know how many times each solution is counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcounting in your case 3, since choosing, for example, $\{a,b\}$ or $\{c,d\}$ for the first cycle results in the same graph.

Each solution in the class is counted $2!$ times, so is contribution to the result is not $\binom42$ but $\binom42/2!$.