# Number of functions that can exist

Tags: combinatorics, functions

[image]

This question appeared in an entrance examination in India. There is no official answer key or solutions provided by the institution. The question according to my knowledge(which isn't that much as I'm just a jee aspirant) is about mapping.

Comment: You are asking how many permutations in $S_5$ are self-inverses.  That happens precisely when the cyclic decomposition of the permutation consists only of cycles of length-2 (*and (unpictured) cycles of length-1*).  Can you continue?

Comment: I suggest:  start by working out the analogous problem for smaller collections.

Comment: Correction : the post [Finding number of functions from a set to itself such that $f(f(x)) = x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760631/finding-number-of-functions-from-a-set-to-itself-such-that-ffx-x) seems to be a duplicate. According to the post there, the answer is $26$.

Comment: $26$ is the correct answer, though perhaps they meant to exclude the identity.  For the other involutions, argue that such a function must have either $1$ or $3$ fixed points and count those cases separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As fellow user, JMoravitz pointed out, we need only consider $f$ where $f$ is injective. Indeed, suppose this is not the case: Then, there exist $a,b\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$. But then $f(f(a))=f(f(b))$, and so if $f(f(a))=a$, then $f(f(b))$ cannot be $b$. As a result, we restrict ourselves to permutations on five elements (i.e. the group $S_5$).

In particular then, we seek the number of elements $g\in S_5$ satisfying $g^2=e$. These happen to coincide with the permutations which can be decomposed into **disjoint** cycles of length $2$ and $1$ since higher order cycles are non-self invertible. In particular, notice that the order of a cycle is its length and the order of the product of cycles is the LCM of the orders of the cycles (again assuming they are disjoint). It suffices then to count these. I will leave the actual counting to you.